# When I enter my command for my discord bot it says that it confirmed the command twice does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

So when I use my discord bots kick command it says everything twice. I've tried restarting Visual Studio Code but it still doesn't work. I haven't duplicated my code or anything so I'm pretty confused on what the problem could be

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');

    const client = new Discord.Client();

   const prefix = '!';


    const fs = require('fs');

     client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
 for(const file of commandFiles){
 const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

 client.commands.set(command.name, command);
 }

 client.once('ready', () => {
```

console.log('KeyBot is online!');
});

```
 client.on('message', message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

   if (command === 'ping') {
     message.channel.send('pong!');
   }
 });



 client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
   const user = message.mentions.users.first();

   if (user) {
    const member = message.guild.member(user);

   if (member) {
   member
  .kick('Optional reason that will display in the audit logs')
  .then(() => {
   message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');

   console.error(err);
  });
   } else {
 message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
 }
  } else {
message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
 }
 }


 });
```

Comment: You have 2 message events firing which is why everything is executed twice. All of your commands should be inside of one message event otherwise this will cause a memory leak.

Comment: But what do I delete then?

Comment: Combine all the content from both events into one single event